# Symfony 3.4 - sending a parameter to a Doctrine prePersist event

Tags: php, events, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I have a few Doctrine `prePersist` events I need to use in order to set up/tweak some Stripe information (Stripe Customer ID, CC info, etc.).  How can I pass my API key into the event if it's located in `app/parameters.yml`?  My event declarations in `app/services.yml` look like:

```
AppBundle\EventListener\ProductHandler:
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }

AppBunlde\EventListener\UserHandler:
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

Answer (score 2):

An event listener is a Symfony service, therefore you can simply pass the parameter as an argument:

```
AppBundle\EventListener\ProductHandler:
    arguments: [ "%my_parameter%" ]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }

…
```

Your constructor would receive the parameter as first argument:

```
class ProductHandler
{
    private $myParameter;

    public function __construct(string $myParameter)
    {
        $this->myParameter = $myParameter;
    }
}
```

If you’re using autowiring and are already injecting other services into the constructor, you can use the following notation:

```
AppBundle\EventListener\ProductHandler:
    arguments: { $myParameter : "%my_parameter%" }
```

This way, it doesn’t matter if `$myParameter` is the first constructor argument; you just need to make sure that it matches the variable name.